# get longchapter of \chapter[]{} in Header

Tags: header-footer

I'm currently working on a book. For that I "definied" my own chapter-command `\mychapter`, which only does

```
\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{\chapter[#1 -- by #2]{#1}
```

This is because I want to show the author of every chapter in the toc. Now I want to get the title in the header. I know that normally I can do that with `fancyhdr`, but there the optional argument is used, which would be in my case `Title -- by author`. But since this would be too long for the header, I would like to get the part of `{...}` in the header. How can I suppress that, so the optional title will be chosen?

Comment: Best approach might depend on your employed class, but `\markboth{#1}{#1}`.

Comment: I'm using the normal `book`class

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Skillmons idea, I could create a working solution:

```
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}[1]{
    {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-30pt}
        \linespread{1.1}\Large\textbf{#1}
        \par\nobreak\vspace*{30pt}}
    \@afterheading%
}
\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{ % chapter with name
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \chapter[#1 --- \textit{von #2}]{#1}\chapterauthor{#2}
    \markboth{\ifnum\value{secnumdepth}>-1 
        \if@mainmatter  
            \thechapter\ 
        \fi
    \fi
    #1}{}
}
```

When I use `\leftmark` with the `fancyhdr`-package now, I get exactly what I wanted.